# Let Users Share Facebook Images

Tags: php, javascript, image, facebook

I would like to build a web app that allows users to post THEIR Facebook images to my web app to share with the greater community.  Does anyone know if this is possible, or which part of the Facebook API would allow this?

My initial digging into the Facebook API seems to require a Facebook ID for any access to images....this is fine when the user is "posting" his/her image to my app....but when another use comes to the website (logged into Facebook or NOT), I want to be able to bring up that first user's image and display it - obviously I might not have any Facebook ID at that point.

Said another way, I'd like the user to basically just provide the Facebook URL to the image he/she wants to share, then I'll store that URL in my database and when a different user comes to the site, I'll load the image from the Facebook URL and display it on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph API for [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) (login required) will return the URL for the image in various sizes. Once you get the proper access token you can fetch a photo's Graph API entry and then just extract and save the CDN image you want.

Comment: So you're saying that my users have to be logged in to see other people's pictures?  That would really limit by usability....I thought that the fact they were "public" pictures would provide me with some way to display them without needing credentials....

Comment: also you mention "save"ing the image....can I just reference the URL in HTML via either PHP or JS rather than actually saving a copy of the image?

Comment: Yes, you can just reference the image URL. And no, users need to be logged in for you to get access to the CDN url of the images, but once you've saved the CDN images you don't have to be logged in to see them.

Comment: Oh ok, so you're saying that I need the user logged in to get access to the URL like facebook.com/images/hglheislnfldsh.jpg  but once I have that URL, I don't need ANY ID again to access that URL?

Comment: That's right: the CDN URLs you get don't need authentication at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, the first user comes in...

1. he will see that he is the first user and a message encouraging him to be the first will pop-up.
2. He [connects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) his Facebook account with your website.
3. You have two options here

   - Just use the user profile picture and for this you just need the `user_id` and no special permission
   - require the `user_photos` permission and build a simple albums browser (like [this](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-user-photo-albums-browser-using-facebook-graph-api/77/) one) for him to choose a photo
4. Save the photo he choose in your DB along with his name, user_id (maybe email) ..etc
5. repeat 2-4 for other users

Just a note, you'll not physically save the image on your server....just the link.